# Scala: why is a type used as a method call?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, parser-combinators

Scala: why is a type used as a method call?

I'm new to Scala and I'm reading "Functional Programming in Scala"
by PAUL CHIUSANO and RÚNAR BJARNASON.

I'm trying to understand the source code of parser combinator in Chapter 9, but I'm stuck by a 
problem: in the source code, `Parser[A]` is declared as a type, but I can see that instances of
`Parser[A]` is used as a method call.

My question is: why instance of a type can be used as a method
call?

```
def or[A](p: Parser[A], p2: => Parser[A]): Parser[A] =
    s => p(s) match {   // ========> p is used as a method call.
      case Failure(e,false) => p2(s)
      case r => r // committed failure or success skips running `p2`
}
```

Link to the source code:

https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/answers/src/main/scala/fpinscala/parsing

Code snippet:

```
trait Parsers[Parser[+_]] { self => 
  .....
}


object ReferenceTypes {

  /** A parser is a kind of state action that can fail. */
  type Parser[+A] = ParseState => Result[A]

  case class ParseState(loc: Location) {
    ......
  }

  sealed trait Result[+A] {
    ......
  }

  case class Success[+A](get: A, length: Int) extends Result[A]
  case class Failure(get: ParseError, isCommitted: Boolean) extends Result[Nothing]

}

object Reference extends Parsers[Parser] {

  ......

  def or[A](p: Parser[A], p2: => Parser[A]): Parser[A] =
    s => p(s) match {
      case Failure(e,false) => p2(s)
      case r => r // committed failure or success skips running `p2`
  }

  .....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you quoted, `Parser[+A]` is explicitly declared as function type

```
type Parser[+A] = ParseState => Result[A]
```

Therefore, values of type `Parser[+A]` can be applied to values of type `ParseState`. The usual syntax for applying a function `p` of type `X => Y` to a value `s` of type `X` is

```
p(s)
```

So, it's just usual function application, it's not even some fancy overriden `apply` method of some user-defined class.

---

A *method call* usually looks as follows:

```
obj.methodName(argument)
```

it requires an object on which the method is called. This can be omitted if the object is `this`, or if you have previously imported

```
import obj._
```

so that all methods of this object are available in the current scope. In all other cases, you need a receiving object on which you invoke a method.

---

The function application

```
p(s)
```

actually desugars into a special method call

```
p.apply(s)
```

but that's an aside, it's not really relevant for the question.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. That helps me a lot. I searched in the source code but couldn't find any method call with the signature ParseState => Result[A]. Am I missing something? Any hints are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: @CodingNow what do you mean by "method call with a signature"? Methods have signatures. Method calls just return values.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Kindly allow me to rephrase: I searched in the source code but couldn't find any method definition with the signature ParseState => Result[A]

Comment: Look at [this code](https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/answers/src/main/scala/fpinscala/parsing/instances/Reference.scala) again. There is a type alias: `type Parser[+A] = ParseState => Result[A]`, that is: `Parser[A]` *is* exactly the same as `ParseState => Result[A]`. There are at least methods `succeed`, `or`, `string`, `flatMap`, `regex`, `scope` etc. that return a `Result[A]`. The entire class does essentially nothing else but defining bunch of functions of type `Parser[A]` (that is, `ParseState => Result[A]`). Every single one of those functions is applicable as `p(s)`.

Comment: Kindly forgive me if my question is stupid. I find that the return 
type of methods `succeed`, `or`, `flatMap` and `string` is `Parser[]`, that's why
I'm confused.

Comment: @CodingNow *was* it confusing, or *is it* still confusing? I hoped that once you saw the type alias `Parser[A] = (State => Result[A])`, that it should become clear? If something is still unclear, then you still have the opportunity to ask...

Comment: Thank you very much for the patience. Actually I'm still confused why the return type of methods `succeed`, `or`, `flatMap` and `string` is `Parser[]` instead of the expected `Result`. Actually I cannot find any method definition with the signature `ParseState => Result[A]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168361/discussion-between-andrey-tyukin-and-codingnow).